# Excel random list maker - output to desired total number

Tags: excel, random

I have a list of info spanning multiple columns, with a number between 2 and 7 assigned to each row in the final column. I'm looking for a way to allow me to enter a number in an assigned cell and have excel output eight random rows that total the entered number. So, for example, I enter the number 42, and it gives me a selection of eight rows totalled randomly 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7... that's one random 2, two random 4s, 3 random 6s and two random 7s. Of course, the inputted 42 could be totalled in a myriad of ways.

One added kink is that the rows also have a column of non-unique names, and I need no duplicates of these names in the final list of eight.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following the scheme:

[image]

add the formula:

```
H3 -> H9 -> =ROUND(RAND()*5+2;0)
H10 -> =IF(AND((B3-SUM(H3:H9)<8);(B3-SUM(H3:H9))>1);B3-SUM(H3:H9);"Recalculate")
```

if the cell H10 is write **Recalculate**, press F9 (force recalculate...)

```
J3 -> =SMALL($H$3:$H$10;1)
J4 -> =SMALL($H$3:$H$10;2) 
J5 -> J10 -> ... 3 to 8
K3 -> =IF(J3=J2;K2+1;1)   ' And autocomplete.
L3 -> =VLOOKUP(INDEX($C$3:$C$10;J3);$C$3:$F$10;K3+1)    ' And autocomplete.
```

**H12 & J12** are only a check of the sum...